# How to optimize these queries with date range?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with weights log with these fields (among others) and sample data:

```
userid  date        weight
---------------------------
1       2015-01-10  100
1       2015-01-15  90
1       2015-01-20  80
2       2015-01-05  120
2       2015-01-15  110
3       2015-01-15  150
3       2015-01-24  140
```

I need to get total weight lost in between dates. Currently, for between **2015-01-09** and **2015-01-21** I use this function in PHP:

```
function get_weight_loss($userid, $start_date, $end_date) {
    global $db;
    $query = "
        SELECT date, weight FROM weight_tracker_log 
            WHERE date=(
                SELECT MAX(date) FROM weight_tracker_log 
                    WHERE date <= '$start_date' AND userid = $userid 
            ) AND userid = $userid 
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db);
    $previous = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ( !$previous['date'] ) {
        /* Get first entry for user */
        $query = "
            SELECT date, weight FROM weight_tracker_log 
                WHERE date=(
                    SELECT MIN(date) FROM weight_tracker_log 
                        WHERE userid = $userid 
                ) AND userid = $userid 
        ";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $db);
        $previous = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    };
    $query = "
        SELECT date, weight FROM weight_tracker_log 
            WHERE date=(
                SELECT MAX(date) FROM weight_tracker_log 
                    WHERE date <= '$end_date' AND userid = $userid 
            ) AND userid = $userid 
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db);
    $next = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysql_free_result($result);
    if ( $previous['date'] && $next['date'] && $previous['date']<$next['date'] && $next['date']>$start_date) {
        return $previous['weight'] - $next['weight'];
    } else {
        return 0;
    };
};
```

It works fine, but calculations are getting longer by time. What it does is:

1. look for user's most recent entry **before** `$start_date`
2. if it does not exist than: look for first user's entry **after** `$start_date`
3. look for **last entry** within range (and get weight)
4. if first date is less than second, than calculate weight difference

Is there any way to optimize the queries or the algorithm itself?

The table was created this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `weight_tracker_log` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'xcart_cutomers',
 `weight` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'grams',
 `date` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
 `is_start_weight` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 `is_end_weight` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=97526 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: Updated with show table create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not seeing any indexes on your table.  That means that every SELECT must walk through the entire table to find the rows that are affected.  Imagine if you had to flip through every page of a 500-page book just to find the two pages that had to do with dogs.

You need to add indexes on your `date` and `userid` columns:

```
CREATE INDEX weight_tracker_log_date ON weight_tracker_log ( date );
CREATE INDEX weight_tracker_log_userid ON weight_tracker_log ( userid );
```

http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is an excellent introduction to how and why to use indexes.

Comment: Should I optimize the table after or adding indexes is enough? I have 41533 records inside.

Comment: It can't hurt to optimize, and it should take you 2 seconds, so just do it.

Comment: Just for the record, with `date` index in: **Done in 2.37 Mins!**, with both indexes in, after optimizing: **Done in 0.20 Mins!**. You rock Andy!

Comment: Thanks.  Now just make sure you go and read up on indexes and when to use them.